# Returning Different Data To Various View Sections

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a "Most Popular" div currently displaying the most popular auction items and an  "Ending Soon" div that I want to display those auctions ending soon. I have successfully queried the database for the "Most Popluar" and returned those results to the page. And I know what the query is for those ending soon, but how do I return both sets of data to the page for the partial view "_AuctionTile" to use?

The following update reflects the suggestions made by Vinutha N --

The View

```
@model IEnumerable<MyAuctionApp.Models.Auction>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row">

    <div id="popular" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h2>Most Popular Items</h2>

        @foreach (var item in Model.mostPopularItems)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_AuctionTile", item)

        }
</div>

<div id="ending" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <h2>Auctions Ending Soon</h2>
       @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           @Html.Partial("_AuctionTile", item)
        }
 </div>
```

The ViewModel

```
using MyAuctionApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyAuctionApp.ViewModels
{

public class AuctionViewModel
    {
    public static List<Auction> mostPopularItems;
    public static List<Auction> endingSoon;

        public AuctionViewModel(AuctionsDataContext db)
        {
        mostPopularItems = db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > 
DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.viewCount).ToList();
        endingSoon = db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > 
DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.EndTime).ToList();
        }
   }
}
```

**The Controller**

```
using MyAuctionApp.Models;
using MyAuctionApp.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyAuctionApp.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class HomeController : Controller

      {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        var db = new AuctionsDataContext();
       var dataModuleObject = new AuctionViewModel(db);
       return View(dataModuleObject);

      //var auctions = db.Auctions.ToArray();
     //var auctions = db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > 
     //DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.viewCount);
     //return View(auctions);
         }
     }
```

As you can see from the attached screenshot however, the 'mostPopularItems' 
property that was initialized in the AuctionViewModel, is not being picked 
up by Intellisense as existing, in the line

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.mostPopularItems)
```

What do I still not have quite right?

[image]

Thanks,
CM

Comment: Create a view model with 2 properties - `IEnumerable<Auction> MostPopular` and `IEnumerable<Auction> EndingSoon` and the in the view `@foreach (var item in Model.MostPopular) { ...` etc

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on this solution a minute if you could.  I like it because of the fact that if this works, all I have to do is add 'Model.MostPopular' or 'Model.EndingSoon' to refer to the data I need. I'm new to this process, and can't quite picture how it works with the view model approach.  Do I create a separate document that is called 'AuctionViewModel', and if so do I specify the most popular and ending soon queries in there?

Comment: Create a `AuctionViewModel` (in a separate `ViewModels` folder) with those 2 properties. In the GET method, initialize it and populate it with the queries - `var model = new AuctionViewModel() { MostPopular = db.Auctions.Where(...), EndingSoon = db.Auctions.Where(...) }; return View(model);` and in the view `@model yourAssembly.AuctionViewModel` (the controller is responsible for getting and populating your data, not the view model)

Comment: @Stephen could you take a look at my updated question.  Thanks. CM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to declare 2 list they are,
list Popularitem and list endingSoon in view model which you are using(if not create and use its a best practice. because u cannot do in the controller)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace DataViewModel.ViewModels
    {
        public class DataViewModel
{
    public list<Auctions> Popularitem { get; set; }
    public list<Auctions> endingSoon { get; set; }
    public CustomerViewModel((datatype)db)
    {
        list<Auctions> Popularitem=db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.viewCount);

    list<Auctions> endingSoon =db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.viewCount);
    }
}
}

in controller 
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new AuctionsDataContext();
        datamoduleobject= new Dataviewmodel(db);
        return View(datamoduleobject);
    }

in view :
@MyProject.Web.ViewModels.DataViewModel
<div id="popular" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h2>Most Popular Items</h2>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Popularitem)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_AuctionTile", item)
        }  
</div>

<div id="ending" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <h2>Auctions Ending Soon</h2>
       @foreach (var item in Model.endingSoon)
        {
           @Html.Partial("_AuctionTile", item)
        }
 </div>
```

and please go through the link i have provided which help u to understand http://tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/how-to-use-viewmodel-in-asp-net-mvc-with-example

Comment: Thank you I will try this and report back if it works for me.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Vinutha--please see my edited question above.  Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisMazzochi Hi, you have to use MyProject.Web.ViewModels.DataViewModel in your view then only you can able to access the property's and you have not included your view model content in question so, i have edited view model section also. have a look .

Answer (score 1):

Use child actions. First, create actions like the following on your `AuctionController`:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult MostPopular()
{
    // get most popular auctions
    return PartialView("_AuctionTile", auctions);
}

[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult EndingSoon()
{
    // get auctions ending soon
    return PartialView("_AuctionTile", auctions);
}
```

Then, in your view, where you want each to display:

```
@Html.Action("MostPopular")
@Html.Action("EndingSoon")
```

Your main view's model should only focus on what it needs to do, not asides like these.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I wasn't paying attention to your HTML. Basically, you would need to create a partial for each section, then. For example:

**_MostPopular.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Auction>
<div id="popular" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <h2>Most Popular Items</h2>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_AuctionTile", item)
    }  
</div>
```

Then, change the child action to return this instead:

```
return PartialView("_MostPopular", auctions);
```

The key here is that the child action creates a separate context, where you can build a view model specifically for this partial view, without affecting what's going on in the main view.

**BONUS**

Display templates can help a lot here too. For example, if you could create a view like `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Auction.cshtml`. Then, any time you call `Html.DisplayFor` with an instance of `Auction`, it would automatically use that view to render it. Additionally, `Html.DisplayFor` can handle enumerables as well. It will simply use the display template for the contained type to render each item in the list. So in your code, instead of iterating over the items in `Model` and rendering a partial view for each, you could then simply do:

```
@model IEnumerable<Auction>
<div id="popular" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <h2>Most Popular Items</h2>
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little about the placement of the @Html.Action("MostPopular") and @Html.Action("EndingSoon") helpers if you can?

What would the following div look like going with your solution?

<div id="ending" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <h2>Auctions Ending Soon</h2>
                   @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_AuctionTile", item)
                        
                    }
                
                </div>

Comment: Could you take a look at my updated question and if you could just see what's not quite right with the approach I am using that was suggested by Vinutha N.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your model declare 2 list and assign the data to lists. In html page use the specific list property in foreach. 
Like,

model.Popularitems
Model.Endingitems

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what you mean by declare "2 list".  
Do you mean declare two lists?  or do you mean declare a ToList() function?

Comment: Sorry i am using mobile to ans questions hence some difficulty in writing. Create two lists

Comment: When you have some time in front of a laptop or something do you mind kindly writing out what you have in mind?  I can't quite picture I'm sorry I'm new to this process. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Either create view model as suggested above or you can pass extra data in view bag as in controller you can set
ViewBag.endingSoon= yourCollection
and use it in your view 
hope It'll help

Comment: Could you take a look at my updated question and if you could just see what's not quite right with the approach I am using that was suggested by Vinutha N.  Thank you.